# I'm searching for SharePoint farm planning tool

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, capacity-planning

Is there any tool that can help me design my farm building plan. For example, I can give number of users and it can show me how many server I will need to use in my farm and if anyone access on internet as a website, how many WFE I will need and others?